# Configure ethernet ports on a router in packet tracer 7

Tags: cisco, router, cisco-commands, packet-tracer, interface

I have some issue to configure the router in Packet Tracer 7.
I have a router with a specific subnet, which is 192.168.1.128/27 .
My first problem is, how can I configure two (or more) ethernet interfaces to the same network, like at the home routers has. So, the router address is the same in both ports, the subnet is the same, ect. (The default settings enables to connect two (or more) different subnets) I tried to set the same ip addres both of the ports, but in that case it says "Overlaps with FastEthernet0/0".

Also how can I set the ethernet interface is WAN connection not LAN connection? Because I want to connect routers together.

NOTE this program uses cisco routers, so maybe if you know how you can set via command line, it will be the same here too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My first problem is, how can I configure two (or more) ethernet
>   interfaces to the same network, like at the home routers has.

Routers route between networks, so each router interface needs to be in a different network. Don't be confused by what you think is a home router. The home router has separate networks on the router interfaces, but you are probably meaning a switch module in a home router. You need a switch or a switch module in a router for that, but those are not router interfaces.

> Also how can I set the ethernet interface is WAN connection not LAN
>   connection? Because I want to connect routers together.

For a router, there really is no real distinction between WAN and LAN. Some interfaces, e.g. serial interfaces, are more likely to be used for WAN connections, while some router interfaces, e.g. ethernet, are more likely to be used for LAN connections, but you could use just about any type of router interface for either connection type. There are no commands that say, "This is a WAN interface." You can connect two routers together with like interfaces.

Comment: yeah you are right, actually I found the home routers has switch ports (that 4 LAN ports) so this is why I can there put same subnet there... in packet tracer 7 there's something like HWIC-4ESW which you can put in the routers or also you can use WDR300N router from the wireless section witch is something like you use at the home. Also if you want to put DHCP to the switch port, you just set the vlan address and normally the DHCP pool.